# How to do firmware updates/upgrades to a Blackberry

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, firmware, blackberry

I have several clients/friends that have Blackberry and wish to update their phone but without installing Windows. Any windows. Just doing it from Ubuntu. How can this be done. The update the mention is for the firmware and new programs for the phone. I do not know much about Blackberries since am more of an android guy. At the end they want support for upgrade/update the Blackberry from within Linux and sync it to the PC (Backups, upload/download stuff to and from it).

I have seen 2 types of projects working on this:

**Linberry** (From Venezuela ;) ) - http://linberry.webcindario.com/

**Barry** - http://www.netdirect.ca/software/packages/barry

but so far neither offers updating the firmware or downloading updates. Are there any Ubuntu blackberry projects I am not aware of.

Comment: I find it interesting that no one has said this before, but search sachesi and you'll find a Linux tool to do it with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firmware updates cannot be applied to BlackBerry devices from Ubuntu, so the answer to your first question is 'No, it cannot be done'.

RIM, makers of the BlackBerry, have decided to support Windows and Mac only.  They also just lost $125 million in three months, a CTO, and a co-CEO, so maybe they are looking for new ideas. Try a feature request via their [contact page](http://us.blackberry.com/contact/).

Sometimes updates can be applied to mobile handsets at the wireless carriers' stores.

The answer to the second part of your question is also 'No'. You didn't miss any other projects that support flashing BlackBerry firmware updates from Ubuntu.

Comment: I was going to argue a couple of things with you but you are very persuasive about your answer. Thanks Tom.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado LOL don't blame me, I've got an Android too!